# Wordpress Comment Moderation Action Hook

Tags: wordpress

I'm using bbPress to create a forum.

I need to use content moderation or a profanity filter.

I don't want to moderate every post before it's posted just those that contain words that are in the list of profanity words.

Wordpress has a comment moderation list but if a word in the list is used the post is added to the moderation queue for moderation but the user gets no message what has happened.

If the user uses a word that is in the list I would like the post to be added to the moderation queue for moderation but the user to get a message about what has happened.

I can't find a plugin to do this so I was thinking if it would be possible to add this functionality in a plugin.

Is there an action hook I could use to hook into the comment moderation process so I could display a message

Comment: I don't know if this will help. http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_comment

But this runs when a comment is made.

Comment: That looks like it might help, thanks